# Best way to import files into a project

Tags: asp.net

I have some .asp files, folders and other documents that make up ASP.net project for a website. Is there a way in visual studio 2019 to compile these files into project automatically?

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you're trying to do this, but if you have a .csproj/.vbproj file you can import an existing project into your solution, otherwise you'll have to add the files on a  folder by folder basis

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a website project which you need to convert into a web-application project.

First, create a new asp.net web-application project. 
Second, remove the default-namespace (empty string).

Third, drag-and-drop all files into your project. 
Drag them from windows-explorer into your visual-studio project-tree.

Done.